# Is there a way to output failed TestNG selenium test stacktraces to the Ant logfile?

Tags: ant, testng

I have the following TestNG snippet in an ant xml script:

```
    <testng haltonfailure="true" outputdir="${webtest.outputDir}" dumpCommand="true">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="project.webtest.classpath"/>
            <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
        </classpath>
        <sysproperty key=".test.web.webdriver.configFile" value="${webtest.configFile}"/>
        <xmlfileset dir="${webtest.classes}/test/web/webdriver" includes="testng.xml">
        </xmlfileset>
    </testng>
```

Sometimes my Selenium tests using this script fail or get skipped, and if this happens I always need to remote into the build server the script runs on in order to check the TestNG results themselves, because they aren't put in the logfile. Is there a Reporter or a Listener or something like that which simply writes the failure cause to the ant log?

Comment: Have you tried setting up a reporter, especially a TextReporter ? cf "reporter" in https://testng.org/doc/ant.html and https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/TextReporter.java